# Windows 10 ssh server: Network not reachable

Tags: windows, networking, ssh, firewall

I'm trying to set up an SSH server on my Windows 10 machine so that I can SSH into it from my Raspberry Pi.

I installed the SSH server and made sure both `ssh-agent` and `sshd` are running. I also added a rule to the firewall that allows incoming connections on port 22.

Whenever I try to ssh into my Windows machine, I get the following error:

`ssh: connect to host X.X.X.X port 22: Network is unreachable`

**Edit:**
Both the RasPi and the Windows machine are in the same local network. I am able to ping the RasPi from the Windows machine but not vice versa. I’m also able to SSH into the RasPi from my Windows PC.

What's the reason for that error and how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the IPs of the Win system and the RasPi? Are they in the same subnet? Can your RasPi ping the Windows system and vice versa? Please don't answer in a comment, but [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769912/edit) the question instead to add info.

Comment: Thanks, I did update my question.

Comment: `Network is unreachable` suggests the two devices are NOT `in the same local network` - and since you are using `local network` (i.e. I'm guessing something in 192.168.x.x) there's no reason to "hide" the IP address, since it's not a publicly routable one

Comment: That’s true, I just thought the exact addresses were irrelevant, that’s why I left them out. Both are indeed of the form 192.168.x.x. But if they weren’t in the same local network, I wouldn’t be able to ping the RasPi from my Windows PC using that local address right?

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the issue was. Pretty stupid, but I simply missed a line and accidentally used the address of a virtual machine installed on the Windows machine.